# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' ,id='productTitle is there in URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I try to run the bellow code I get the following error 
The ids exists `productTitle` and `priceblock_ourprice`

Error

```
    title= soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.amazon.com/Canon-PowerShot-SX420-Complete-Accessory/dp/B01D0PKF0Q/ref=sr_1_2?crid=H9FUF2YIZOLC&keywords=camera&qid=1578179990&sprefix=cam%2Caps%2C147&sr=8-2'
headers ={"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763'}
page =requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
title= soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)
price=soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
print(title)
print(price)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _is there in URL_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but `html.parser` doesn't parse the HTML from Amazon well. Change to `lxml` or `html5lib` parser and you will see your output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Canon-PowerShot-SX420-Complete-Accessory/dp/B01D0PKF0Q/ref=sr_1_2?crid=H9FUF2YIZOLC&keywords=camera&qid=1578179990&sprefix=cam%2Caps%2C147&sr=8-2'
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763'}
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml') # <-- change to 'lxml' or 'html5lib'

title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)
price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()

print(title)
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
Canon PowerShot SX420 IS Digital Camera (Black) with 20MP, 42x Optical Zoom, 720p HD Video & Built-In Wi-Fi + 64GB Card + Reader + Grip + Spare Battery and Charger + Tripod + Complete Accessory Bundle
$289.95
```